# Hide prices for non logged in members except one category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make some changes to code I have found off here that will allow me to hide all the prices of my woocommerce store EXCEPT for one category.

The category I want to display prices for all the time is 'courses' but I want to hide the rest of the products prices until the user is logged in. I am trying to make changes to this code

```
add_action( 'init', 'bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );
  
function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {   

    if (! is_user_logged_in() && 
        ! has_term( 'courses', 'product_cat' ) ) 
    { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );   
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 31 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 11 );
    }
}
 
function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
    echo '<a class="button product_type_simple" href="' . 
    get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . 
    __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing every action that outputs the `price` simply, remove the price.

This code would filter the `get_price_html()` function from the `WC_Product` class and return an empty string.

```php
function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
    global $product;  
    if (! is_user_logged_in() &&
        !has_term( 'courses', 'product_cat', $product->get_id())) 
    { 
        add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', '__return_empty_string', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 ); 
    }
}
```

or... to add your click to login button...

```php
function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
    global $product;
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && 
        !has_term( 'courses', 'product_cat', $product->get_id())) // add product ID to check if that specific product is part of courses category. 
    { 
        add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see'), 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 ); 10);
    }
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
    // Modify the function to return the value, not echo it.
    return '<a class="button product_type_simple" href="' . 
    get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . 
    __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

**Revised Answer Additions**

- Access the current `$product` inside your loop to check if it's part of `courses` category.
- Remove `add to cart button` from single product pages if the product is part of the category `courses`

Comment: This is still hiding the price on the courses product pages. I should of mentioned I want to be able to hide the ability to add to cart until the user is logged in too. This is for every product that doesn't fall under the 'Courses' category..

Comment: Ok, at that point you would start using `remove_action` to remove the add to cart buttons, ill add those to my answer

Comment: Hi Mate - thanks for your reply. However, this is still hiding all of the prices site wide.. not all except one category..